# Angular mat-table UI not updating on datasource update - (signalr-azure service live update)

Tags: angular, angular-material, signalr, azure-signalr

We are using server-stream updates from the signalr-azure service to get live updates from the backend, and the WebSocket is blocked on the client-side(browser).
We can observe that the data is being updated in debugging, but the mat-table UI is not updated without any mouse events.

Steps to reproduce:

Create a signalr-service for live updates
Create a connection with signalr service and render the incoming data in a mat-table
Block the web-socket on client-side(browser), use event stream updates to receive data from signalr
Create a button to reload the data, onClick of the button expected to update the mat-table with recent data.

Expected Behavior
mat-table should load the data onClick of the button

Actual Behavior
mat-table datasource being updated but not reflected in the UI until any mouse event is performed (cursor movement)

Environment
Angular: 13.0.x
CDK/Material: v 13.0.2
Browser(s): Chrome Version 108.0.5359.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Operating System (e.g. Windows, macOS, Ubuntu): Windows 10

We were trying to use signal-r azure service to show live update of data.